# Handling Large Requests to API

Tags: api, design-patterns, architecture, microservices

Are there best practices for how to pass large lists between services? I see some recommendations to pass S3 file URLs between services if the payloads can be large, but that seems like a step backwards because if the data is in S3 then the client can't use the server's API schema to validate the request as easily as if the data were passed in a list.

I can't process the data in small batches because it all needs to be processed at once.

Example:

Service B has API 1.

API 1's job is to receive a list of cars and when all cars are received to take some action on each car. All cars need to be acted on, it's not OK to take the action on only some cars.

Service A wants to send Service B 400,000 cars to store in Service B's database.

Should Service B structure API 1's API so that it expects:

- A list of cars
- A URL for an S3 file that contains a list of cars
- Something else

Comment: It seems to me that you want to validate a file upload using API schema validation. I would separate the two, especially because you can compress a file and make the call efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It hugely depends on what actual requirements and constraints are. Sending a big amount of data via API in one go is usually not a good idea due to multiple reasons (network interruptions, memory consumption, etc.). If you don't have transactional requirements - you can just send data in small batches and (re)design the API to support that. Potentially you should consider completely switching from synchronous calls via API to asynchronous ones for example using some messaging pipeline (using Kafka for example).

Comment: Good point about transactions. I've updated my question to have a transactional requirement that all items need to be sent before the server can take its action on the list.

Comment: @user7340 it still can be done by sending data in batches, though a little bit complicating the API.

Comment: You mean that the server could introduce some process for ensuring every batch had been received before taking action on any item? That makes sense, but I am hoping to avoid complicating the services. I'd rather have a somewhat complicated interface.